# the following errors are found during the installation of an open source software, UNCeqR on z shell

Tags: software-installation, errors

I am trying to do somatic mutation detection via the open source software, UNCeqR

I got following error was detected on mac z shell during installation.

```
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 11.
not ok 1
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1.tar.gz
```

I would like to ask for any advice to proceed.

Comment: Did you look at the `cpan-testers` results as suggested? Is this the entirety of the output? What command did you run?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Perl compilation error:

(Perl libraries) Math::CDF-0.1 -- Generate probabilities and quantiles from several
statistical probability functions

> conda install -c bioconda perl-math-cdf

> cpan INSTALL Math::CDF

This module provides cumulative probabilities [P(X <= x)] and
quantiles [given p, returns x such that P(X <= x) = p] from several
statistical probability distributions.

This package provides a perl interface to DCDFLIB

https://metacpan.org/release/CALLAHAN/Math-CDF-0.1/source/README

`make` and `make test` of Perl libraries Math::CDF-0.1 in the installation are not okay

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bd8TklsUPMqDRDn7zImGEXI9Nk84vkfU/view?usp=sharing